# How can I send multiple data from view to action data?

Tags: arrays, json, asp.net-mvc

I have an adding product form. I try to do as wizard.

Firstly, I add product detail that I have `Add_Product` view.

After that, I get the id of the added product.  With `redirectToAction` I send the id to `AddProductOption`.

The problem start over here. The product has lots of options.

For example, the product is a phone. `OptionName:Memory`, `Option=32gb`.

The client will enter enter both the optionName and the option value.

I create dynamic input.  If the client wants to add extra input for optionName and option, I have done dynamic input but how do I get multiple data from view to action? I hope to explain my problem.

```
 <div class="form-group" style="float: left !important">
     @Html.Hidden("productId",Model.Id)
     <label name="proid" for="full_name" class="form-label">Özellik Tip</label>
     <input class="ozellik form-control SpeCaption" type="text" name="SpeCaption" id="full_name" placeholder="Özellik Tip" style="width: 40% !important;" />  //OptionName
     <input class="ozellik form-control SpeDescription" type="text" name="SpeDescription" id="full_name" placeholder="Açıklama" style="width: 20% !important;" />  //Option
 </div>
```

Comment: Please separate the code and text

Comment: if you are adding dynamic control, then you need to send data using ajax.

Comment: Prepared JSON object and post the server it's work easily please refer the [lnk](https://www.wiliam.com.au/wiliam-blog/ajax-with-mvc-passing-a-list-of-objects)